# Is there a way to assign the primary category for a product in demandware using the Open Commerce API (OCAPI)?

Tags: demandware

The primary category of a product is present in the product document (primary_category_id) in the DATA API but cannot be written. After sending a PATCH update of the product with a different primary_category_id, it doesn't change.

Is there a way of doing this through the OCAPI?

Answer (score 1):

Can be some limitation for **PATCH** Method.Fields that can be updated: 
name, 
page_description, 
long_descripton, 
page_title, 
page_keywords, 
brand, 
ean,
upc, 
manufacture_sku, 
manufacture_name, 
searchable, 
unit, 
searchable, 
online_flag, 
default_variant_id.

Try with PUT Method. PUT https://hostname:port/dw/data/v19_1/products/{id}. Also, 
please check Request Document.

Comment: I tested with PUT directly and POST + method override but it isn't still updating the primary_category_id. It does other custom fields, though.

Comment: Also, I got the primary_category_id field in the GET response before but it doesn't seem to work now.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it does not appear that this is possible to manage via OCAPI.

I suspect that in the future you'd be able to achieve it using the following resources:

```
DELETE /catalogs/{catalog_id}/categories/{category_id}/products/{product_id}
```

followed by:

```
PUT /catalogs/{catalog_id}/categories/{category_id}/products/{product_id}
```

With a `ProductCategoryAssignment` document in the `PUT` call.

However, this would require that Salesforce adds those attributes to the `ProductCategoryAssignment` document.

The reason I suggest this is where it would be added is that within a catalog import document (XML) the flags are associated with a similar resource representation. eg:

```
    <category-assignment category-id="gear-bags-backpacks" product-id="NSF4003100">
        <primary-flag>true</primary-flag>
    </category-assignment>
```